# Aramaic word from Col. 22 of the Dead Sea Scrolls Genesis Apocryphon: אשכח

Tags: grammar-dikduk, aramaic, non-rabbinic-judaism

I want to apologize in advance if this is not the type of question for this forum. I have been searching around and unfortunately there do not seem to be any places specifically for asking questions pertaining to the inner mechanics of Aramaic.

This is from the "Genesis Apocryphon", Column 22.

Col. 22.7: 
 והוא רדף בתרהון עד דבק לדן *ואשכח* אנון...

I understand there is a vav conjunctive before the word. What puzzles me is why there is an א before the word. This should indicate imperfect 1cs (plus the vav makes it preterite). However, in context, this doesn't make any sense at all. It would be the only 1cs verb used in this entire passage. Everything else in this section is in the 3rd person. Why the random 1cs switch this one time? The translation I have is from Daniel Machiela, who translates it as 3rd person "he found...". So what is it supposed to be?

Comment: The aleph prefix, in this case, is likely equivalent to the Hebrew על meaning 'by' or 'on'. That "דבק לדן' and "שכח אנון" are place names. You might find The Practical Talmud Dictionary and Grammar for Gemara & Targum Onkelos by Rabbi Yitzchok Frank of great help in your efforts. You can find them on Amazon. They are excellent reference books.

Comment: @YaacovDeane א as a prefix is equivalent to Hebrew על only in the Babylonian Talmud. אשכח אנון is a verb and its object (in the Aramaic of the Targumim you are more familiar with it is written as one word אשכחנון). It's not a place name

Comment: Always there is a aleph אשכחיה לפלוני is very frequently used in Gemara, נפק דק ואשכח

Comment: @ba And the "Genesis Apocryphon" is according to which nusach? If you don't know with certainty, just say, "I'm not sure."

Comment: @YaacovDeane From Israel as opposed to Babylon

Comment: @ba I'm not looking at the actual text, only the few words the OP has provided. It's talking about pursuing after them up to Davek (Devek?) in the territory of Dan and near or by Shachah Anon... If the complete text suggests another meaning, that's also fine.

Comment: @ba It's possible the "ואשכח אנון" is starting a new phrase discussing why he was making the pursuit. That he had some kind of payment with him called "שכח אנון". Without further context, it's difficult to say what is being discussed. It doesn't need to be understood as a verb conjugation.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I'm beginning to think your view of it as a place name should be taken as a considerable possibility. However, immediately after ואשכח אנון in line 7 (beginning line 8) it says this: שרין בבקרת דן. So the full idea would read: "And he pursued them until he reached Dan and Shachah Anon in the valley of Dan." I do not know about the location. Was Shachah Anon in the valley of Dan?

Comment: @YaacovDeane It seems to me that if the location is right, the text could be interpreted either way. 1) "And he pursued them until he reached Dan and he found them in the valley of Dan."  2) And he pursued them until he reached Dan and Shachah Anon in the valley of Dan."

Comment: @YaacovDeane or, regarding your 'payment' idea, do you think it could be saying that he caused them to pay in the valley? Figurative of executing vengeance on them? Because that is what the text is saying in the fuller context. This is the story of Abraham taking 312 men and fighting the kings... So with this interpretation it would read: "And he pursued them until he reached Dan and he caused them to pay in the valley of Dan." I'm not sure about the full range of meaning behind Shachah, or if this was a figure of speech in ancient Israel. Is this a possible interpretation as well?

Comment: @Phillip I would prefer to see the complete Hebrew text that you are looking at before giving my thoughts about translation. As I commented before, only 8 words were provided. In that context, “Davek l’Dan” sounds like a place. The balance of the phrase could go in many different directions, either clarification of place or perhaps with some kind of tax bill. Without context, it’s impossible to clarify.

Comment: @Phillip ‘Anon’ is possibly a reference to an agricultural tax that was due to the King of that particular territory.

Comment: @Phillip ״אשכח״ can mean ‘with whatever was forgotten’... So in context, the justification for pursuit was a tax delinquency.

Comment: @Phillip 312? Or 318 ‘men’? The latter being in agreement with the written text of the Torah which according to Rashi means Eliezer, gematria of 318. So Avraham brought the chief executive managing his business accounts with him. In the context of a tax dispute that would make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CAL dictionary](http://cal.huc.edu/oneentry.php?lemma=%24kx+V&cits=all) describes the root שכח as:

> A highly irregular verb. The initial aleph is prothetic, but the resulting form is treated as a quasi afel, often with a preformative vowel in a instead of original e. Hence the active participle in mem, already in OfA, which even shows the distinctive heh of the early h/afel.

So the word is conjugated with an א prefix like an אפעל verb in the perfect aspect for every person (in this case third person masculine), but otherwise it is conjugated like a normal פְּעַל verb (e.g. infinitive למשכח). The letter ו in ואשכח is only conjunctive and has no effect on the aspect.